# how to remove duplicate value in a cell Hive table

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, duplicates, impala

I got a column in my Hive SQL table where values are separated by comma (,) for each cell. Some values in this string are duplicated which I want to remove. Here is an example of my data:

```
test, test1, test,test1
rest,rest1,rest1,rest    
chest,nest,lest,gest
```

The result should replace any duplicates:

```
 test,test1      
rest,rest1       
chest,nest,lest,gest
```

I want to remove duplicates. Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Impala or Hive? They are very different

Comment: In Hive would be more ideal. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is working.

Comment: If it works, please accept/vote the answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Hive.
Split to get an array, explode, use collect_set to get array without duplicates, concatenate array using concat_ws.

Demo (Hive):

```
with your_table as(
select stack(3,
1, 'test, test1, test,test1',
2, 'rest,rest1,rest1,rest',   
3, 'chest,nest,lest,gest'
) as (id,  colname)
)

select t.id, t.colname, concat_ws(',',collect_set(trim(e.elem))) result
  from your_table t
       lateral view outer explode(split(colname,',')) e as elem
group by t.id, t.colname
```

trim() is used to remove spaces which present in your data example.

Result:

```
t.id    t.colname                 result    
1       test, test1, test,test1   test,test1
2       rest,rest1,rest1,rest     rest,rest1
3       chest,nest,lest,gest      chest,nest,lest,gest
```